# How to update a user using the 'Ion Auth' authentication library in CodeIgniter 4 framework

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Below is my code snippet. I want to reduce the balance of a user in the database using Codeigniter 4?

```
dd($this->ionAuth->update($this->ionAuth->users()->row()->id, ['balance' => 1000]));
```

*I'm using [Ion Auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) for updating.
It's just a big burden when updating the database using modelling data.

Comment: Can you give us a full query you are trying to produce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you intend to use `$this->ion_auth->user()` instead of `$this->ion_auth->users()`.

Also keep in mind that executing a dump and die on `$this->ion_auth->update(...)` [returns a boolean](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#:%7E:text=update()-,Update%20a%20user.,-Parameters) *not* the updated user data.

##### References:

`users()` [gets ***all*** users](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#:%7E:text=users()-,Get%20the%20users.,-Parameters).

> users()
> Get the users.
>
> Parameters
>
> 'Group IDs, group names, or group IDs and names' - array OPTIONAL. If an array of group ids, of group names, or of group ids and names are passed (or a single group id or name) this will return the users in those groups.
>
> Usage
>
> ```php
> $users = $this->ion_auth->users()->result(); // get all users
> ```

`user()` [gets a single user](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#:%7E:text=user()-,Get%20a%20user.,-Parameters).

> user()
> Get a user.
>
> Parameters
>
> 'Id' - integer OPTIONAL. If a user id is not passed the id of the currently logged in user will be used.
>
> Usage
>
> ```php
> $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
> echo $user->email;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

look here authentcate library for ci4

```
https://github.com/lonnieezell/myth-auth
```

go there  download it

ionAuth is not compablitablke with ci4

Comment: @pliz ***ionAuth is not compatible with ci4***. That is basically incorrect. [Ion Auth 4](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/tree/4#ion-auth-4) was specifically designed to support *CodeIgniter 4*.